# ZYNQ board doesn't recognized usb flash drive

Tags: usb, embedded-linux, zynq

I'm working with a Zynq board (RFSoC4x2) that has embedded Linux installed on it. The board comes with USB 3 ports. However, when I connect any USB storage-based drives, such as an external HDD or thumb drive, nothing happens. I expect to see entries like /dev/sda* so I can mount them, but they're nowhere to be found. Additionally, when I connect and disconnect the flash drive to the board, there's no output in the dmesg command. I should note that I've successfully used these ports to connect Wi-Fi dongles.

I would appreciate any help.

You can see that with connecting USB flash drive to the board there is nothing new at the output of dmesg command. The same thing happens with the lsblk and lsusb commands.
[Output of dmesg command before and after connecting the USB flash drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh18Q.png)

Comment: "*there's no output in the dmesg command*" -- Either you don't know how to extract messages from the syslog, or these devices are not compatible with the port(s) of the board. Even if all the proper drivers were not available, the basic USB negotiation would be reported on insertion/detection. Regardless, your post is off-topic for this site. Superuser.com seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

For working USB host port the following things are important to use them properly.

- Check and setup PS's USB port settings for your board in Vivado and make its XSA export for Linux image building via Yocto or Buildroot.
- Setup a correct device-tree for your board with an USB host enabled node.
- Check Linux kernel config to have Zynq USB driver in the kernel, correctly.